# Jquery append after ajax not working every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jquery append. This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:
        "/getcars.php",
    data: {
        model_car: sessionStorage.getItem("model")
    }
}).done(function(msg) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
    $("#model").empty().append('<option value="-1">Model</option>');
    var string_option = "";
    Object.keys(obj.model).forEach(function(key) {
        string_option += '<option value="' + obj.model[key] + '">' + obj.model[key] + '</option>';
    });
  
    console.log(string_option);
    $("#model").append(string_option);
})
```

This code work very well, but not every time. (only the append option not working. This: console.log(string_option) it`s ok every time).

Can you help me, please?

Thank you!!

Comment: "_This code work very well, but not every time_" What you mean by "every time" here? Are you making multiple ajax calls like this or running this ajax call in a loop?

Comment: can you please include the html section you are appending it and also one sample response from the server side

Comment: This ajax is called when page is load. I check if I have specific string in URL and I run the code. For example: Now I press f5, work. After 10 seconds I will press again f5, not working. Html section: <select class="form-control model" id="model" name="model" style="">
             <option value="-1" selected="">Model</option>
</select> . First append it`s ok ($("#model").empty().append('<option value="-1">Model</option>');).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to put the code to be executed after the document is fully loaded using the "$( document ).ready" jQuery event

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:
            "/getcars.php",
        data: {
            model_car: sessionStorage.getItem("model")
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
        $("#model").empty().append('<option value="-1">Model</option>');
        var string_option = "";
        Object.keys(obj.model).forEach(function(key) {
            string_option += '<option value="' + obj.model[key] + '">' + obj.model[key] + '</option>';
        });
      
        console.log(string_option);
        $("#model").append(string_option);
    })

});
```

You can learn more about this on the below link
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, can you sign my answer as answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem could be that you run the `.append()` before DOM is loaded. If this is the problem you can try 2 methods:

- put this javascript code inside footer.
- add to your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     //... your ajax request
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem is document ready. My script it is in global.js in footer and I missed document ready here. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the response on Ajax success sometimes it happens due to malformed JSON is sent back with a 200/OK